# The titleContentColor of TopAppBar in Jetpack Compose is always set to the primary color in theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material3

I am trying to change the color of titleContentColor to onPrimaryContainer in my theme. However, the color does not change according to onPrimaryContainer but instead seems to always take the value of the primary color in my theme.

```
 ExampleTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Scaffold(topBar = {
                TopAppBar(colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
               ),
                title = {
                    Text("Small Top App Bar")
                }
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        ScrollContent(innerPadding)
    }
}
```

My ExampleTheme

```
@Composable
fun ExampleTheme(

    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = false,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColors
        else -> LightColors
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )

}
```

Even when using a custom color (e.g. Color.White) it does not change and still takes the value of the primary color. Is this normal?

```
 ExampleTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Scaffold(topBar = {
                TopAppBar(colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    titleContentColor = Color.White,
               ),
                title = {
                    Text("Small Top App Bar")
                }
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        ScrollContent(innerPadding)
    }
}
```

Comment: can i ask where are you trying to see the top app bar is it in preview or in physical device?

Answer (score 1):

For using your own theme you have to use `ExampleTheme` instead of `MaterialTheme`

Comment: I am using the ExampleTheme itself

Comment: Preferably provide a bit more detailed answer with example code.